# Why my sessions die even when I only call install packages and packages library?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am simply trying to install some packages and call some packages to use in Rstudio. I have been doing this for a long time and have never faced a problem. However today, when I type this code

```
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("tidyr")
install.packages("xlsx")
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(xlsx)
```

My R died. I tried restarting session, restarting the computer, reinstalling packages, but it keeps failing like this. Some advise me to reinstall dplyr with depedencies = TRUE, but it doesn't work either. Anyone here may have a cluse ?

[image]

Comment: ```dplyr``` and ```tidyr``` are part of ```tidyverse```, no need to install them individually. Have you looked at your memory and cpu usage while loading the packages? If your memory is too busy/full RStudio will abort the session due to lack of memory space needed for the packages.

Comment: How are you running RStudio? Are you on a windows/mac computer? What version are you running? Does it only die after the very last line? Do all the others run correctly?